# What is the best approach to use log4net in different layers with in a solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, log4net

I have a web api solution with following different layers. I like to implement unity log4net extension in my project and want to use this across different layers.

- DL
- BL
- Web (contains controller classes and using Unity for IOC)

> Do i need to install log4net package only in web layer which is the main entrance point? or should it be installed in all layers?

Comment: What is stopping you from using log4net in all these layers ?

Comment: question updated

Comment: show some code of your use of log4net

Comment: Why can't you just add a reference to and use log4net in each project you need to use it in? You can even use single solution wide config file...

Comment: reference to what?

Answer (score 0):

Only the Web (Application Entry Point) really needs to reference the 3rd part dependency

As I explainer in one of your previous questions.

Create a core project for your custom logger

```
public interface ILogger {
    //...
}
```

All other projects will reference that code project and make use of the logging abstraction.

For example the following is in the Data Layer

```
public class ExampleRepository : IRepository {
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public ExampleRepository(ILogger logger){
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    //...use logger
}
```

The data layer has no need to reference the external dependency as it relies only on the custom abstraction.

Further up, lets say the Business Layer has the following service

```
public class ExampleService: IService {
    private readonly ILogger logger;
    private readonly IRepository repository;

    public ExampleService(IRepository repository, ILogger logger){
        this.logger = logger;
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    //...use logger and repository
}
```

The business layer has no need to reference the external dependency as it also relies only on custom abstractions.

At the highest level, the Web project. Again assuming a simple controller

```
public class ExampleController: Controller {
    private readonly ILogger logger;
    private readonly IService service;

    public ExampleController(IService service, ILogger logger){
        this.logger = logger;
        this.service = service;
    }

    //...use logger and service
}
```

Through out this entire example, all classes are dependent on abstractions and not implementation concerns.

You want to use log4net as the logging implementation for the entire system so the Web project references the necessary dependencies and then create

```
public class Log4NetWrapper : ILogger {
    private readonly ILog log; //log4net 

    public Log4NetWrapper(ILog log) {
        this.log = log;
    }

    public void LogMessage(string msg) {
        log.Info(msg);
    }

    //...
}
```

At this point only the Web project has need to reference the 3rd party dependency.

Now any time a dependent class want to use logging that it be done via log4net.

Great, in the composition root of the Web project you register the abstraction and implementation along with any extensions needed to use log4net.

```
container = new UnityContainer();
container.AddNewExtension<Log4NetExtension>();
container.RegisterType<ILogger, Log4NetWrapper>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

So now when ever a `ExampleController` needs to be resolved from the container the `Log4NetWrapper` will be injected to the entire object graph that is currently executing in the Web project.

In this scenario, log4net is an implementation concern. Because of the above design, all classes involved are only concerned with abstractions and not concretion.

So long story short,

> Do i need to install log4net package only in web layer which is the main entrance point?

**YES**

> or should it be installed in all layers?

If your architecture is cleanly designed, then **NO**.

DI is being used throughout this entire example. When designed correctly, only the composition root needs to be aware of any external dependencies.

Comment: many thanks for the detail explanation. Basically we are going to install log4net package in two places 1) web project 2) Logger project . This raises one question in my mind, why can't i reference log4net dll in all layers instead of creating a separate logger project? Does it break DI rules?

Comment: @user1263981 It is more about tight coupling design. If in the future you need to change the logging framework being used (for what ever reason) you will have to make many breaking changes. While with a clean design the changes would a lot less with fewer breaking changed.

Comment: @user1263981 It does not beak rules per say because this is a matter of your preference.